# $a+b+c+abc=4,$ prove $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\ge \frac{4+\sqrt{2}}{4}.$

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, holder-inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca>0$ and satisfy $a+b+c+abc=4.$ Prove that$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+a^2}}\ge \frac{4+\sqrt{2}}{4}.$$
The equality holds at $(0,2,2)$ so that I can not use **AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz** to kill it as usual symmetrical inequality.

I tried Holder inequality$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)[(2\sqrt{2}-1)c+a+b]^3\ge(2\sqrt{2}+1)^3(a+b+c)^3 ,$$which saves equality occur but leads to wrong inequality. Counter example: $a=b=\dfrac{1}{100}$.

I hope Holder works in better yields. I also tried Mixing variables without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the following will help.

By Holder $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(ab+\sqrt2c^2)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(ab+\sqrt2c^2)^3}}\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(\sqrt2a^2+ab)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(ab+\sqrt2c^2)^3}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$8\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(\sqrt2a^2+ab)\right)^3\geq(1+2\sqrt2)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(ab+\sqrt2c^2)^3,$$ which saves the case of an equality occurring and it's true for $b=c=0$ and $a=4$.

I checked also that it's true for $b=a$ and $c=\frac{4-2a}{1+a^2},$ where $0\leq a\leq2$.

The term $(\sqrt2c^2+ab)^3$ we can get by the following way.

Note by Holder $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(a^2+b^2+kc^2+mab+nac+nbc)^3\geq$$
$$\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}((2+k)a^2+(m+2n)ab)\right)^3.$$
The equality occurs, when $$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+a^2}}\right)||$$
$$||\left((a^2+b^2)(a^2+b^2+kc^2+mab+nac+nbc)^3,(b^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2+ka^2+mbc+nab+nac)^3,(c^2+a^2)(c^2+a^2+kb^2+mac+nab+nbc)^3\right),$$ which gives
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(a^2+b^2+kc^2+mab+nac+nbc)=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}(b^2+c^2+ka^2+mbc+nab+nac)=\sqrt{c^2+a^2}(c^2+a^2+kb^2+mac+nab+nbc).$$
For $b=c=0$ and $a=4$ the first equation gives $$4\cdot16=0\cdot16k,$$ which is possible, when coefficients before $a^2$ and $b^2$ in the expression $(a^2+b^2+kc^2+mab+nac+nbc)^3$ are equal to $0$ and for the equality case we obtain:
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(c^2+mab+nac+nbc)=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}(a^2+mbc+nab+nac)=\sqrt{c^2+a^2}(b^2+mac+nab+nbc),$$ which for $a=b=2$ and $c=0$ gives:
$$2\sqrt2\cdot4m=2(4+4n),$$ which for $n=0$(because with $0$ we obtain something simple) gives $m=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and we got an expression $$(\sqrt2c^2+ab)^3,$$ for which Holder saves the case of an equality occurring.

Comment: It is nice but very hard to think of. Thank you very much.
How did you use the term $c^2+Kab$?

Comment: @Ha Diep Xuan It's the Bacteria's method. I am ready to explain.

Comment: It seems interesting. The name "Bacteria" recalls me something.... Could you tell more ?

Comment: Oh, now I see your adding. It is very interesting, thank you very much

Comment: I am try to apply uvw for the rest of proof. The trouble is determining the sign $f'(u,v,w)$

Comment: How did you prove your claim?

Comment: @TATA box I wrote: "Maybe the following will help". I think, $uvw$ will help, but I still don't see a full proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It seems $8\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(\sqrt2a^2+ab)\right)^3\geq(1+2\sqrt2)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(ab+\sqrt2c^2)^3$ is not true. Check $a = 3/2, b = 5/2, c = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts**.

WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a, b, c)$.

Using
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}} \ge \frac{1}{b + c}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2 + a^2}} \ge \frac{1}{c + a}$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} + \frac{1}{b + c} + \frac{1}{c + a} \ge 1 + \frac{\sqrt 2}{4}. \tag{1}$$

We can prove that
$$\frac{1}{b + c} + \frac{1}{c + a} \ge 1. \tag{2}$$
(The proof of (2) is given at the end.)

If $a^2 + b^2 \le 8$, clearly (1) is true.

In the following, assume that $a^2 + b^2 > 8$.

We have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} - \frac{\sqrt 2}{4}
 = \frac{\frac{1}{a^2+b^2} - \frac18}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} + \frac{\sqrt 2}{4}}
 \ge \frac{\frac{1}{a^2+b^2} - \frac18}{\frac{1}{8}}
 = \frac{8}{a^2 + b^2} - 1. \tag{3}
$$

Using (3) and $\frac{1}{b+c} \ge \frac{1}{4 - a}$ and $\frac{1}{c + a}\ge \frac{1}{4 - b}$,
it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{8}{a^2 + b^2} - 1 + \frac{1}{4 - a} + \frac{1}{4 - b} \ge 1$$
which is true for all $a, b > 0$ with $a + b \le 4$.

---

*Proof of (2)*:

If $ab < 1$, using $c \le 1$ and $a + b \ge 2$,
we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{b + c} + \frac{1}{c + a} - 1
 &= \frac{-c^2 - (a + b - 2)c - ab + a + b}{(b + c)(c + a)}\\
 &\ge \frac{-1 - (a + b - 2) - ab + a + b}{(b + c)(c + a)}\\
 &= \frac{1 - ab}{(b + c)(c + a)}\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}

If $ab \ge 1$, using $a + b + c + abc = 4$, we have $a + b + c + c \le 4$. Then by Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$\frac{1}{b + c} + \frac{1}{c + a}
\ge \frac{4}{(b + c) + (c + a)} \ge 1$.

We are done.

Comment: (+1) Does Jichen lemma help? It suffices to prove 3 conditions.

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, it is true.